# Angular 1 - Compile ng-if condition into string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-compile, angularjs-interpolate

I have this string :

```
this.badge = `<span class="badge">{{ notification}}</span>`
```

to interpret the {{ notification}} expression I do :

```
this.badge = this.$interpolate(this.badge)(this)
```

What i would like to do now is to add an `ng-if` in the `span` element :

```
this.badge = `<span ng-if="notification > 0"class="badge">{{ notification}}</span>`
```

But the `$interpolate` service does not support this, how can I "compile" the condition of ng-if ?

Answer (score 0):

you can to use local `scope`:

```
this.badge = '<span ng-if="'+(scope.notification > 0)+'" class="badge">'+scope.notification+'</span>';
```

Comment: .setAttribute("ng-if", "notification > 0");